# PhantomJS cannot open a page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to get a html version of my url because of my backbone structure with multiple javascript code but this lines work only sometimes... Yes, sometimes works and the page content is loaded but sometimes phantom stucks and is not able to open the page. In fact, it doesn't log anything.

I'd played with timeouts but I'd got nothing. Any help? It appears to be a no deterministic behaviour. Thanks in advance!

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('myurl', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address')
    phantom.exit(1); 
  } else {
    console.log( "Successful page open!" );
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have also found the same issue. Can't do anything except to work around it.

Comment: Finally I worked in a solution repeating this code until I got the page content loaded through a condition like `strpos(result_page_open,'<html')`.